# Display multiple rows and associated columns from multiple worksheets in a new sheet

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with multiple worksheets, very similar data of each sheet, columns are a=person, b=task, c=department, d=due date. On a separate sheet I was trying to display all the tasks associated to one person, myself `steve` in this example.

Can it be done?

Column Headers = Person,    Task,   Department, Due Date
Sample Rows = Steve,    Present critical paths for French & Mandrin online Academy, Academy,    May 22-2015

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Like are all the tasks located on one sheet just multiple rows?  Or are you wanting to search over all the sheets and grab all the tasks for that person?

Comment: Hi there, thanks chances (I realized my subject line needed some changes) yes I'd like to grab all the rows across multiple sheets for that one person. I bit like I would normally use a filter on a single sheet.

Comment: Check out Pivot tables, read this: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved with a PivotTable (eg [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120)) but frankly filtering to select `Steve` and moving and/or copy/pasting to suit seems just as easy, or easier. Though easier still of course may be to combine all sheets into one and use PTs, filtering, Subtotal and such like to view the data to suit. There is much more inherent versatility in one sheet of all data than in many sheets with some of the data each.